# haskell: delete a specific string inside a list

Tags: string, haskell

I wrote this function to delete any word inside a list that starts with '{' and ends with '}':

```
delete []=[]
delete c@(x:xs) | head x=='{' && last x=='}'= rep x " " (unwords c)
                | otherwise = delete xs
```

I am using the helper function rep:

```
rep _ _ [] = []
rep a b s@(x:xs)= if isPrefixOf a s
              then b++rep a b (drop(length a)s)
              else x: rep a b xs
```

When I call the delete function on a list of strings like the one below,, it deletes successfully the first string "author" but leaves the 2 others "reference", "title":

["{author}","has","stated","that","{reference}","     {title}","has","been","published","..."]

Please tell me that is missing in my function?

Thank you,

Omar

Comment: After a match is found you do not recurse on `delete`, so only the first match gets removed. Also, I think `x` is always a prefix for `unwords (x:xs)`, so I'm unsure about why you check for that. Actually, using `unwords` for this looks already quite strange. Can't you write the whole thing as `filter (some predicate here) listOfStrings` ?

Comment: @chi Once again your comment directed me to the solution. So I used a filter: filter(\x -> head x=/'{')myList. And it solved my problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: But remember that `head` will fail on empty strings, so you better check for empty strings **before** using head.

Comment: @Ingo is this why I'm getting this error message: Prelude.head: empty list?

Comment: Exactly! That is the error for head on an empty list.

Comment: @Ingo I thought I checked for empty strings with delete []= [] ? Am I missing something else?

Comment: This is the outer list of strings that you are checking, but strings are themselves lists (as you know very will, since you use `head` and `last`on them).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138277/discussion-between-omar-and-ingo).